# http 403 when accessing an url in perl

Tags: perl

I want to access a webpage but I'm getting 403, failure for [THIS](http://econsumercomplaints.in/2011/03/16/httpwww-rudrainfomatics-com-fraud-people-who-register-domain-for-us-on-the-name-of-after-taking-advance-payments-now-just-not-responding-domain-is-closed-be-ware-of-them/) url.
But when I access using Firefox it shows HTTP 200 OK.

This is the code I'm using to access it:

```
    my $agent = LWP::UserAgent->new(env_proxy => 1,keep_alive => 1, timeout => 30, agent => "Mozilla/5.0");
         my $header = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $link);

         my $request = HTTP::Request->new('GET', $link, $header);

          my $response = $agent->request($request);

          if ($response->is_success){
........
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code worked fine on my system accessing one of my own sites.  I would guess that the website you hitting is allergic to automated requests.  The user agent you are using is very minimal, and they may reject anything that does not look real.  Here is a more genuine agent:

"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/11.0.696.71 Safari/534.24"

Comment: When I used full browser identification as mentioned by Bill it worked then.

Comment: It didn't work for me. Is there another recommended userAgent?